# Get available time ranges from an array of busy time ranges

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, momentjs

Lets say you have an array of **BUSY** time ranges for a meeting

```
[{'start':'9:00 AM', 'end':'10:00 AM'},
{'start':'12:00 PM', 'end':'2:00 PM'},
{'start':'5:00 AM', 'end':'7:00 PM'}]
```

I would like to get in return an array of **AVAILABLE** times in a 24 hour frame, that are the opposite of the above times. Like...

```
[{'start':'00:00 AM', 'end':'9:00 AM'},
 {'start':'10:00 AM', 'end':'12:00 PM'},
 {'start':'2:00 PM', 'end':'5:00 PM'},
 {'start':'7:00 PM', 'end':'11:59 PM'}]
```

I have tried using moment.js as well as https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-range, specifically the `.subtract()` method.

I am aware of similar stackoverflow questions but couldn't find ones that were applicable to this format, in javascript, with momentJS, and elegant ES6 array method solution.

Comment: To get a help from the community, please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question

Comment: I'm trying now to first get an array of all 15 minute increments in a given day. Declare array `var array = []` . Declare start of day `var m = moment().startOf('day').unix();` . Loop! `for ( i = 0; i <= 96 ; i++){ m+=900; array.push(m); }` Then once I have this array I'm thinking I `array.splice(start, deleteCount)` and the altered array will be valid **available** times

Comment: I hope you have a typo here: {'start':'5:00 AM', 'end':'7:00 PM'} otherwise there is an overlap

Comment: I am sure I have been overthinking this. I cannot believe we need moment.js for simple integer math. I will try again

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```js
function giveUtc(start) {
  var t = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")
  var t1 = t + " " + start
  return moment(t1, "YYYY-MM-DD h:mm A").format()

}


const timeRange = [{
    'start': '9:00 AM',
    'end': '10:00 AM'
},
{
    'start': '12:00 PM',
    'end': '2:00 PM'
},
{
    'start': '5:00 PM',
    'end': '7:00 PM'
},
{
    "start": "11:00 AM",
    "end": "3:00 PM",
},
{
    "start": "6:00 PM",
    "end": "9:00 PM",
}]


timeRange.sort((a, b) => {
  var utcA = giveUtc(a.start)
  var utcB = giveUtc(b.start)
  if (utcA < utcB) {
return -1

  }
  if (utcA > utcB) {
return 1


  }
  return 0
})
const availableTimeArray = []

let endTimeFarthest = moment(giveUtc("0.00 AM"))
let startTimeMinimum = moment(giveUtc("12.59 PM"))
timeRange.forEach((element, index) => {
  let currentEndTime = moment(giveUtc(element.end))
  const currentStartTime = moment(giveUtc(element.start))
  if (currentStartTime.isBefore(startTimeMinimum)) {
startTimeMinimum = currentStartTime
  }
  if (currentEndTime.isAfter(endTimeFarthest)) {
endTimeFarthest = currentEndTime
  }
  /* console.log(startTimeMinimum.format("h:mm A"), endTimeFarthest.format("h:mm A")) */
  if (index === timeRange.length - 1) {
if (timeRange.length === 1) {
  availableTimeArray.push({
    start: "00:00 AM",
    end: currentStartTime.format("h:mm A")
  })
}
availableTimeArray.push({
  //start: currentEndTime.format("h:mm A"),
  start: endTimeFarthest.format("h:mm A"),
  end: "11.59 PM"
})

  } else {
const nextBusyTime = timeRange[index + 1]
const nextStartTime = moment(giveUtc(nextBusyTime.start))
if (index === 0) {
  availableTimeArray.push({
    start: "00:00 AM",
    end: currentStartTime.format("h:mm A")
  })
}
let endTimeToCompare = currentEndTime.isBefore(endTimeFarthest) ?
  endTimeFarthest :
  currentEndTime
if (endTimeToCompare.isBefore(nextStartTime)) {
  availableTimeArray.push({
    start: endTimeToCompare.format("h:mm A"),
    end: nextStartTime.format("h:mm A")
  })
}

  }

})
console.log(availableTimeArray)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

> I have used utc timestamp to compare between timings and assumed that all the interval belongs to a single day. Some edge case might be missing but you can take the idea. I have made use of greedy algorithm. First sorting all the interval based on the start time. Then iterating through the sorted array to pick correct interval

Comment: This is incredible. I see that you first handled the edge times, then worked your way between the ranges...On top of that you kept it in UTC with your helper function. Thank you this is why stackoverflow is what it is

Comment: @stack26 It doesn't work well. Add another timeRange 'start': '11:00 AM', 'end': '3:00 PM' and see results

Comment: Yes you are right, missed this edge case, editing my answer. Now check and please let me know

Comment: Still some edge case. Change the last 'end' time from 9:00PM to 6:30PM. Thank you for your effort @stack26

Comment: @daniherculano: let me check it. Thanks for mentioning it

Answer (score 2):

I have been overthinking this.
Simple loops should be enough

I have not tested this 100% so there may be edge cases.

```js
const busy = [{'start':'9:00 AM', 'end':'10:00 AM'},
{'start':'12:00 PM', 'end':'2:00 PM'},
{'start':'5:00 PM', 'end':'7:00 PM'}];
const last = busy.length-1;
let avail = [];
function norm(t) {
  let [,hh,mm,ampm] = /(\d{1,2}):(\d{2}) ([AP]M)/.exec(t);
  return {"hh": ampm=="PM"? +hh+12:hh,"mm":mm }  
}
function makeUSTime(hh) {
  return (hh>12?hh-12:hh)+":00";
}
for (let i=0,j=0;i<busy.length;i++) {
  for (;j<=24;j++) {
    if (norm(busy[i].start).hh>j) {
      avail.push({"start":makeUSTime(j),"end":busy[i].start});
      j=norm(busy[i].end).hh;
      break;
    }
  }
}
if (norm(busy[last].end).hh<24) avail.push({"start":busy[last].end,"end":"11:59 PM"});

console.log(avail)
```

Comment: thank you for your response! I'm not sure who downvoted your attempt but I appreciate it!

Comment: Yeah, I wonder too. At least they could have told me why they did not like the suggestion. It seems to work as intended - possibly needs some more work, but I left that up to the implementer