# Get available time from an array of busy hours PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I have a php array of booked time as :

`print_r($data)`

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [start_date] => 2019-09-26
                    [start_time] => 07:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2019-09-26
                    [end_time] => 09:00:00
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [start_date] => 2019-09-26
                    [start_time] => 12:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2019-09-26
                    [end_time] => 14:00:00
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    [start_date] => 2019-09-26
                    [start_time] => 16:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2019-09-26
                    [end_time] => 17:00:00
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 13
                    [start_date] => 2019-09-26
                    [start_time] => 19:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2019-09-26
                    [end_time] => 20:00:00
                )

            [4] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [start_date] => 2019-09-27
                    [start_time] => 07:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2019-09-27
                    [end_time] => 08:00:00
                )

            [5] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [start_date] => 2019-09-27
                    [start_time] => 12:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2019-09-27
                    [end_time] => 14:00:00
                )

            [6] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [start_date] => 2019-09-27
                    [start_time] => 16:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2019-09-27
                    [end_time] => 18:00:00
                )

            [7] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 14
                    [start_date] => 2019-09-27
                    [start_time] => 19:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2019-09-27
                    [end_time] => 20:00:00
                )

            [8] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [start_date] => 2019-09-28
                    [start_time] => 07:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2019-09-28
                    [end_time] => 10:00:00
                )

            [9] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [start_date] => 2019-09-28
                    [start_time] => 12:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2019-09-28
                    [end_time] => 13:00:00
                )

            [10] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 11
                    [start_date] => 2019-09-28
                    [start_time] => 16:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2019-09-28
                    [end_time] => 17:00:00
                )

            [11] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 15
                    [start_date] => 2019-09-28
                    [start_time] => 19:00:00
                    [end_date] => 2019-09-28
                    [end_time] => 20:00:00
                )

        )

)
```

Now, I want to find the details of available hours for each day.
To check this, let's consider business hours is from `07:00:00` to `20:00:00`

Now, I want to find the available time between these hours i.e `07:00:00` to `20:00:00` by filtering all the above booked time.

```
$available_hour =  => Array(
            [2019-09-26] => Array(
                        [0] => Array(
                            ['start'] => 09:00:00
                            ['end'] => 12:00:00
                        )
                        [1] => Array(
                            ['start'] => 14:00:00
                            ['end'] => 16:00:00
                        )
                        [2] => Array(
                            ['start'] => 17:00:00
                            ['end'] => 19:00:00
                        )
            )
            [2019-09-27] => Array(
                        [0] => Array(
                            ['start'] => 08:00:00
                            ['end'] => 12:00:00
                        )
                        [1] => Array(
                            ['start'] => 14:00:00
                            ['end'] => 16:00:00
                        )
                        [2] => Array(
                            ['start'] => 18:00:00
                            ['end'] => 19:00:00
                        )
            )
            [2019-09-28] => Array(
                        [0] => Array(
                            ['start'] => 10:00:00
                            ['end'] => 12:00:00
                        )
                        [1] => Array(
                            ['start'] => 13:00:00
                            ['end'] => 16:00:00
                        )
                        [2] => Array(
                            ['start'] => 17:00:00
                            ['end'] => 19:00:00
                        )
            )
)
```

This is the basic idea, I have seen similar problem in stack overflow here, [Get available time ranges from an array of busy time ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407713/get-available-time-ranges-from-an-array-of-busy-time-ranges), however, I want to deal it in php instead of js.

I have tried my best to represent a sample data array (although this is a full array instead of object), its ok to work with it. Here, is the [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f9bfe4c1100a8dede9bfd6462e63f577136f1196) link.

Comment: use array_walk function

Comment: @Usira Could you please help it with code.

Comment: no need of that func just loop through the array and create new array

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
$res = [];
foreach($x as $value)
{
    if(array_key_exists($value['start_date'],$res))
    {
        end($res[$value['start_date']]);         // move the internal pointer to the end of the array
        $key = key($res[$value['start_date']]);
            if(empty($res[$value['start_date']][$key]['end']))
            {
                if($value['start_time'] >= '07:00:00' && $value['start_time'] <= '20:00:00')
                {
                    $res[$value['start_date']][$key]['end'] = $value['start_time']; 
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if($value['end_time'] >= '07:00:00' && $value['end_time'] <= '20:00:00')
                {
                    $res[$value['start_date']][] = ['start' => $value['end_time']];
                }
            }
            if(!empty($res[$value['start_date']][$key]['start']))
            {
                if($value['end_time'] >= '07:00:00' && $value['end_time'] <= '20:00:00')
                {
                    $res[$value['start_date']][] = ['start' => $value['end_time']]; 
                }
            }
    }

    else
    {
        if($value['start_date'] >= '07:00:00' && $value['start_date'] <= '20:00:00')
        {
             $res[$value['start_date']][] = ['start' => "07:00:00",'end' => $value['start_time']];
             end($res[$value['start_date']]);         
             $key = key($res[$value['start_date']]);
             $res[$value['start_date']][++$key] = ['start' =>  $value['end_time']];

        }
    }
}
foreach($res as $key => $result)
{
foreach($result as $k => $v)
{
    if(!array_key_exists('end',$v))
    {
        unset($result[$k]);
    }
}
$new[$key] = $result;
}
```

The final result will be in `$new` variable.

Comment: this don't work as well as there is no mention of business period means start time 07:00:00 and 20:00:00.
Just change the start time of the first booked time slot (2019-09-26) i.e instead of 07:00:00 to 08:00:00 and your code will fail

Comment: You can check this link. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/da92de1da30690fe0be1d753935bfb31f7684ee4

Comment: Could you show me where you had included about the business hours i.e 7 am to 8 pm.? Please check this code http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dd9cc50ac76a0d6c37dc8232a54541fae6df3e7b Here, I have update the first start time to 8am then why it is still showing the available time from 9-12 instead it should have shown 7am to 8 am as available time as first. I think you need to limit the loop somewhere between 7 am to 8pm instead of taking start time from the first array element

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice little trick, assuming the structure of the array/object contains "items".

Working example: https://3v4l.org/Wat8i works with PHP 5.4+.

```
<?php

$datetimes = [
    "items" => [
        [
            "id" => 1,
            "start_date" => "2019-09-26",
            "start_time" => "07:00:00",
            "end_date" => "2019-09-26",
            "end_time" => "09:00:00"
        ],
        [
            "id" => 4,
            "start_date" => "2019-09-26",
            "start_time" => "12:00:00",
            "end_date" => "2019-09-26",
            "end_time" => "14:00:00"
        ],
        [
            "id" => 9,
            "start_date" => "2019-09-26",
            "start_time" => "16:00:00",
            "end_date" => "2019-09-26",
            "end_time" => "17:00:00"
        ],
        [
            "id" => 13,
            "start_date" => "2019-09-26",
            "start_time" => "19:00:00",
            "end_date" => "2019-09-26",
            "end_time" => "20:00:00"
        ],
        [
            "id" => 2,
            "start_date" => "2019-09-27",
            "start_time" => "07:00:00",
            "end_date" => "2019-09-27",
            "end_time" => "08:00:00"
        ],
        [
            "id" => 5,
            "start_date" => "2019-09-27",
            "start_time" => "12:00:00",
            "end_date" => "2019-09-27",
            "end_time" => "14:00:00"
        ],
        [
            "id" => 10,
            "start_date" => "2019-09-27",
            "start_time" => "16:00:00",
            "end_date" => "2019-09-27",
            "end_time" => "18:00:00"
        ],
        [
            "id" => 14,
            "start_date" => "2019-09-27",
            "start_time" => "19:00:00",
            "end_date" => "2019-09-27",
            "end_time" => "20:00:00"
        ],
        [
            "id" => 3,
            "start_date" => "2019-09-28",
            "start_time" => "07:00:00",
            "end_date" => "2019-09-28",
            "end_time" => "10:00:00"
        ],
        [
            "id" => 6,
            "start_date" => "2019-09-28",
            "start_time" => "12:00:00",
            "end_date" => "2019-09-28",
            "end_time" => "13:00:00"
        ],
        [
            "id" => 11,
            "start_date" => "2019-09-28",
            "start_time" => "16:00:00",
            "end_date" => "2019-09-28",
            "end_time" => "17:00:00"
        ],
        [
            "id" => 15,
            "start_date" => "2019-09-28",
            "start_time" => "19:00:00",
            "end_date" => "2019-09-28",
            "end_time" => "20:00:00"
        ]
    ]
];

$openinghours = [];

function openinghours($times) {

    global $openinghours;

    $openinghours[$times["start_date"]][] = [
        "start" => $times["start_time"],
        "end" => $times["end_time"]
    ];

}

array_map("openinghours", $datetimes["items"]);

var_dump($openinghours);
```

It basically makes a new array without modifying the old one and no if statements needed.

**[EDIT1]**

And quick additional `foreach()` function to show the dates and times: https://3v4l.org/uhUeS

```
foreach($openinghours as $date => $times) {
    echo "{$date} : {$times[0]["start"]} - " . end($times)["end"] . "\n";
}
```

**[EDIT2]**

If you expect people or yourself to change the opening hours so that `id` `1` can have `07:00:00` to `20:00:00`, I suggest you change the output structure to ignore `start` and `end` and just pick first and last of the dates: https://3v4l.org/jMvCP

```
function openinghours($times) {

    global $openinghours;

    $openinghours[$times["start_date"]][] = $times["start_time"];
    $openinghours[$times["start_date"]][] = $times["end_time"];

    sort($openinghours[$times["start_date"]]);

}

array_map("openinghours", $datetimes["items"]);

var_dump($openinghours);

foreach($openinghours as $date => $times) {
    echo "{$date} : {$times[0]} - " . end($times) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, you need to sort the times first as well right?

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question very well. All the array are the booked time. that means for 2019-09-26 one hall (lets say it opens at 7 am and close at 8 pm) is booked from above mentioned hours. Means this hall is booked for 7-9, 12-14,16-17, and 19-20 this means the hall is still available for booking for 9-12,14-16, and 17-19. However, if the hall is already booked for 8-9, 12-14,16-17, and 19-20, then your code fails in this case check here https://3v4l.org/2jJDt. It won't show 7-8 in your result when this time is still available because the hall opens at 7 am