# Looking for an efficient way to return a portion of a string

Tags: javascript, regex, string, typescript

I'm working in JavaScript/TypeScript.

I have a string that may include a some tags that indicate importance or urgency.  Example:

A: "Remind me to go to the store tomorrow.  It is really important"

B: "It is important to go to the store tomorrow."

I have built a method to identify where the importance phrase exists in the main phrase.  For instance, for string A, the importance phrase comes between characters 40 and 62.  In phrase B, it comes between character 0 and 16.

I have a JSON object that describes the start/stop points of the importance phrase:

`this.importancePosition = { start: 40, stop: 62 }`

No problem.

So I have other phrase element detectors:

`this.urgencyPosition = { start: 20, stop: 30 }`

`this.locationPosition = { start: -1, stop: -1 }`

and so on.

By the way, I'm using -1 as an indicator that the token has not been found.  Also, the sub-phrases may not come in order.

**So here's the question:**

Let's say I have the main phrase and the locations of each of the detected sub-phrases.  Now, I want to return everything from the main phrase that is not part of one of the sub-phrases.

I have this:

`[aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa[subphrase]bbbb[subphrase]ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc[subphrase]]`

I want to return this:

`[aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbb ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc]`

What is an efficient way to do this?  I've considered regex-ing them out of the main string, but is that the cleanest way?

Comment: If you have the indices, you can work just with those to reconstruct the string (regexing is prone to mistakes as well if the same substring occurs multiple times in the original). You'd probably benefit most from looking up algorithms that focus on "finding the ranges of free times given a schedule" type problems. Instead of "times", it's just "indices" but it would work the same. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48407713/get-available-time-ranges-from-an-array-of-busy-time-ranges

Comment: In my case, I ended up using the regex approach because I knew the exact phrasing extracted from the original, so the regex reliability would be high.

But I learned a bit by reading the link you provided.   Thanks for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming mainPhrase is a string, try:

```
var replacedPhrase = mainPhrase.replace(/\[subphrase\]/g, " ");
```

I'm not sure how rusty I am with regex's in JS but I think this should work.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getSpliceList(dataType, positionKeyList) {
  return positionKeyList.reduce((list, positionKey) => {
  
    const { start, stop } = dataType[positionKey]
    list.push([start, stop]);

    return list;

  }, []).sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);
}
function getReassambledStringBySpliceConfig(str, dataType, positionKeyList) {
  let delimiter = '';

  return getSpliceList(dataType, positionKeyList)
    .reduceRight((characterList, spliceItem) => {

      characterList.splice(
        spliceItem[0],
        spliceItem[1] - spliceItem[0] + 1,
        delimiter
      );
      if (!delimiter) {
        delimiter = ' ';
      }
      return characterList;

    }, str.split('')).join('');
}

const sampleItem = {
  foo: "foo",
  importancePosition: { start: 85, stop: 95 },
  bar: "bar",
  urgencyPosition: { start: 33, stop: 43 },
  baz: "baz",
  locationPosition: { start: 18, stop: 28 },
};
const sampleText = '[aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa[subphrase]bbbb[subphrase]ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc[subphrase]]';

const expectedResult = '[aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa bbbb ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc]';

console.log(
  '(ordered) splice list ...',

  getSpliceList(
    sampleItem,
    ['urgencyPosition', 'importancePosition', 'locationPosition']
  )
);

console.log(
  'reassembled string ...',

  getReassambledStringBySpliceConfig(
    sampleText,
    sampleItem,
    ['urgencyPosition', 'importancePosition', 'locationPosition']
  )
);
console.log(
  'does reassembled string equal expected result ?..',

  getReassambledStringBySpliceConfig(

    sampleText,
    sampleItem,
    ['urgencyPosition', 'importancePosition', 'locationPosition']

  ) === expectedResult
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @user3093211 ... are there any questions regarding the above approach?

Comment: Wow, you did a lot of work.  Much more than I ever expected.  I really like the generalize-ability of the approach you've suggested.  My current application doesn't require that same broad application, but I'm for sure putting a post-it note on this solution for the future.  It is a thoughtful way to do it.